# Retrieving image file location from database not displaying

Tags: php, mysql, image

Ok, so here is what I am looking to do...I want to be able to upload a picture to the specified folder, and the path is inserted into the database(That part is done)
Then I need to pull the images from the database and display them on the index.php page. I know it's a simple process but I must be missing something.(grrr) I just can't seem to get the image to display on the index.php page, I can display the file location on getimage.php and echo out the image, but can't seem to reference the location to the img src and get it to display on index.php

Here is the code for the index.php page:
I want to be able to pull the image from getimage.php and display the image on the index.php page.

```
<a href="gallery.html">
<img src="getimage.php?id=18" alt="" width="200" height="133" /></a>
```

Here is the getimage.php page:

```
<?php
  include("connect.php");
  $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE p_id='$id'");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  {
  header("content-type :image/jpeg");
  $image = $row['image'];
  echo $image;
  }
?>
```

So what this script is going to do is:
On the index page there are 3 pictures, there will be preset slots in the database for them. The user will be able to change these 3 photos anytime by uploading another photo (the upload script will update the old ones with the new ones.) the pictures will be displayed by their ID.

I could simply run 3 queries, 1 for each ID but I was thinking maybe i'm missing an easier way to do it.

Help is very much appreciated...Thank you.

(Yes I am aware of SQL injection as well as deprecation)

Comment: Why are you using a loop for one row?

Comment: create function for get file path not new file because it's not call file like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is absolutely not correct correct. You have to change the line to :

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'
         .base64_encode($image['file_data']).'" width=300 height=200/>";
```